# About YouTube search list API V3

Tags: youtube-api

In my application, I have used youtube.search.list API v3 for searching whole videos included in specific channel.

Example:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[CHANNEL_ID]&q=[KEYWORD]

'q' is parameter for search keyword.
In my case, I used only 'q=' without keyword because I'd like to search whole videos.
It's working well at least until yesterday(27.Aug). but now, the server response is always 'totalResults: 0'

Could you tell me whether it's temporary wrong operation or the policy about this API is changed?

You can test above problem in the below url :
http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been reported to the gdata issues list five times in the last 24 hours or so. Regardless of whether it's deliberate or not, there's a lot of people concerned.

The first instance report: 
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6598